# Is there other ways of passing a php $_GET variable from url to a js variable?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get query string values in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

I know you could do this by echoing the variable $_GET['whatevervariable'] to a js variable.i was just wondering if there are other methods that can also do this?

Comment: Can you be more specific? What do you want to do?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-query-string-values-in-javascript -- you can do it in pure javascript.

Comment: No, it’s not true that you can (normally) “echo” a variable from a PHP script into a JavaScript variable. Perhaps a code fragment will help others answer your questions.

Comment: aw my topics going to be shut down again for being unclear.anyway i just want to know if there are other ways of getting the $_GET['variable'] from the url and passing it to a js variable without using <?php echo $_GET['variable'] to set a js variable. No specific uses. i just want to pass the $_GET variable to a js variable using different method if there are other methods out there.

Answer (score 1):

This will provide the entire $_GET array to your JavaScript app:

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
_GET = <?php echo json_encode($_GET); ?>;
--></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `$_GET` superglobal is just an array of the querystring.

You can fetch the querystring in javascript with `window.location.search`, but to use it like `$_GET` will need some sort of parsing and usually a few regular expressions to handle difficult characters etc.

Just try `var qs = window.location.search;` and then figure out exactly what you need, and how you will get it.

The easy solution if doing it inline is just echoing $_GET into a variable, like in danorton's answer.